# Scrollable subcontent that doesn't change the height of the entire site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I've been lately working on a project of mine that I'd really like to finish, not only Photoshop wise but also HTML/CSS wise and I've encountered a problem.

[image]

This is the website & some help graphics - I would like to make the content inside the white rectangle scrollable, but everything outside the rectangle should stay exactly as it is. I'm going to either use Skrollr or Parallax Scrolling, but I first need to figure out how to make it so the entire website has a fixed height and never stretches, while the subcontent div can be scrolled down and up.

Comment: using CSS, you can add `overflow:auto` to the white rectangle div

Comment: You can try [jScrollPane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/)
You can also find a lot of Demo pages on the author page!

Comment: @HamedAliKhan Tried your solution and it works exactly the way I wanted. I can't believe it's so simple. Thank you very much everyone who posted here.

Comment: @Mark: jScrollPane is not very flexible because it uses jquery UI so it is not very flexible. i use http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/ instead, think it's way more flexible.

Comment: @herrfischer Nice, that was the other, I used it 3 days ago, but I completely forgot the name! :)
And yes, that's way better!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Overflow: auto;` does this for you, [in a heartbeat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow).

Comment: Ah, too late I see. Good to see it's worked out. Try googling first next time, though.